# System.Timers.Timer set to 24hours interval

Tags: c#, timer

Is it right to set the `Interval` property to ensure the timer is started at an interval of 24 hours everyday

```
this.NotificationTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
this.NotificationTimer.Interval = 86400000D;
```

I am converting 24 hrs to 86400000 ms.
Please confirm if this is the right approach/value. Else, explain the reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about basic arithmetic and SI units, not programming.

Comment: If you want a daily task, you're probably better off using Windows Scheduled Tasks, anyway.

Comment: I don't see any problem. Yes you can use it in this way.

Comment: When unsure of the total milliseconds, the [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110)) struct can convert from any interval type, i.e., `double ms = TimeSpan.FromHours(24).TotalMilliseconds`

Comment: @MetroSmurf good comment, I incorporated this into my answer.

Answer (score 7):

The `Interval` property gets or sets the interval, expressed in milliseconds, at which to raise the Elapsed event. So what you do is correct. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx).

A bit more optimized and probably a touch easier to read is using the `Timer` constructor:

```
this.NotificationTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(86400000D);
```

In terms of calculating the correct time in milliseconds you can call a `TimeSpan` method. This improves readability; disadvantage is a slightly slower execution:

```
this.NotificationTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromHours(24).TotalMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers and tips.